# TransferHandler, JTable & JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll

The problem is thus: I have a slightly modified JTable implementation inside of a JScrollPane. The JTable then has a TransferHandler registered so that items can be reordered, and inserted into each other.

The problem is that once the drag and drop functionality that we get for free from Java kicks in, the scrolling doesn't get the appropriate MouseEvents for autoscroll to work.

I have seen obscure rferencs to this on the JavaDoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/dnd.html).

But I cannot find a diffinitive solution, or anyone else referencing the same problem... So is there anyone put there with some helpful knowledge?

Comment: I think that Oracles DND tutorial contains code example about JTable in JScrollPane and DND

Comment: don't quite understand: _functionality that we get for free from Java kicks in_ - are you doing dnd from scratch? If so, why? Or why not disable the default? In other words: a SSCCE would be helpful :-)

Comment: Err, the DND fuctionality that the TransferHandler sits inside of is what I am Talking about. An extension of the explanation: The DND functionality consumes the mouse events as it uses them to find where the start and end positions are for the DND operation. This means that the autoscroll functionality that we get for free in Swing never gets the mouse events for scrolling. So, to counter this the TransferHandler

Comment: needs to be modified to provide the autoscroll functionality. the above linked article vaguely mentions that there are examples for this, but no trace of them exists elsewhere. I am wondering if anyone knows where I can come across some implementations, or examples of this functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cause of this behaviour is the drag and drop behaviour and the fact that
the TransferHandler isn't configured to support autoscroll. The TransferHandler
is taking over the mouse events once a drag and drop is initiated, which means
the autoscroll behaviour of the JTable doesn't get executed.

There are only obscure and vague references to this in the documentation, links
are provided below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/dnd.html
(keyword: BasicDropTargetListener)

http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d5/teaching/ss05/is05/javadoc/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicDropTargetListener.html

Comment: hmm ... still don't get what you want to achieve: disable the autoscroll? Because autoscrolling while dragging seems to be the default behaviour (at least for a [JList with a custom TransferHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14043897/203657), didn't try on a JTable)

Comment: Drag And Drop on a JTree was the issue. The functionality required to be able to move a node to a new location on the JTree. Now the issue is that in order to drag from the top of a tree to the bottom (with a scrollpane) the tree doesn't autoscroll without the user shifting the mouse cursor back and forwards on the bottom of the scrollpane. In theory the user should just have the mouse cursor (holding the node) outside of the scrollpane and it should shift automatically.

Comment: hmm ... just checked with a quick custom handler on JTree: that's the default behaviour (win, both jdk6/7), can't reproduce the need for back/forth movement of the mouse, it starts auto-scrolling at the top/bottom of the visible tree rectangle. Suspect that there's something else wrong. You might consider showing an SSCCE to get help in tracking it down :-) Plus edit your questin to reflect the fact that you were talking _JTree_ (vs. JTable)