# Enable drop just for specific targets in Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag & drop in java with two `JList` instances.
The basic flow works fine. However, when I'm dragging a string from one list, I want to restrict the drop target only for the second list. 
I noticed that when I'm dragging a string from one list to my desktop so it creates a file containing this string.

Is there any way to avoid such situations?

```
public class SampleDnD extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SampleDnD();

    }
    /**
     * new form of frame sample contain 2 JLists with drag enabled.
     */
    public SampleDnD(){
        JList l1 = new JList();
        JList l2 = new JList();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        DefaultListModel listModel1 = new DefaultListModel();
        DefaultListModel listModel2 = new DefaultListModel();

        String[] list1 = new String[]{"1","3","5","7","9"};
        String [] list2 = new String[]{"0","2","4","6","8"};
        for(int index=0;index<list1.length;index++){
            listModel1.add(index, list1[index]);
            listModel2.add(index, list2[index]);
        }
        l1.setModel(listModel1);
        l2.setModel(listModel2);
        l1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        l2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        l1.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        l1.setDragEnabled(true);
        l2.setDragEnabled(true);
        l1.setTransferHandler(new ListTransferHandler());
        l2.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
        l2.setTransferHandler(new ListTransferHandler());
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(l1);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(l2);

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();

    }
    public class ListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {


        /**
         * We only support importing strings.
         */
        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
            // Check for String flavor
            if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
       }

        /**
         * Bundle up the selected items in a single list for export.
         * 
         */
        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
            JList list = (JList)c;
            String value = (String)list.getSelectedValue();
            return new StringSelection(value);
        }

        /**
         * We support only move actions.
         */
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return TransferHandler.MOVE;
        }
        /**
         * Perform the actual import.  This demo only supports drag and drop.
         */
        public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
            if (!info.isDrop()) {
                return false;
            }
            JList list = (JList)info.getComponent();
            DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
            JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
            int index = dl.getIndex();
            boolean insert = dl.isInsert();
            // Get the string that is being dropped.
            Transferable t = info.getTransferable();
            String data;
            try {
                data = (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { return false; }

            if (insert) {
                listModel.add(index++, data);
            } else {
                // If the items go beyond the end of the current
                // list, add them in.
                if (index < listModel.getSize()) {
                    listModel.set(index++, data);
                } else {
                    listModel.add(index++, data);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        /**
         * Remove the items moved from the list.
         */
        protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable data, int action) {
            JList source = (JList)c;
            DefaultListModel listModel  = (DefaultListModel)source.getModel();
            if(action == TransferHandler.MOVE)
            {
                listModel.remove(source.getSelectedIndex());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Make the app. full-screen & non-resizable?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Full screen is not an option.

Comment: i don't get you, SSCCE is an example of code. i can't give an example for something that im lookign solution for, if i had solution so probably i wouldnt ask in first place.
so i will ask again: is there any code to Enable drop just for specific targets in Swing?

Comment: *"..SSCCE is an example of code."*  Yes. Show me an example code with 2 lists, with D'n'D enabled that show the 'drag to desktop' problem & I am more likely to load that in an IDE, compile it & *experiment with solutions*.  I mean post a short example of the **broken** code.

Comment: Andrew is right. You write you have already some code working for you, but with some issues you want to solve. You probably can isolate this specific class, make dummy classes around it (to provide data, for example), wrap it in a simple mono-frame main class, and post it somewhere. Then we have a starting point to "play" with. Either think we are too lazy to come up with such code (but making it ourself might deviate too much from your own goal) or that making half of the road toward us brings you closer of the solution...

Comment: sorry, im new here and im trying to post the shortest code i can. i don't see here any button that will get me to a comment window except the fast reponse window. and my code it's too long for this.

Comment: +1 for the SSCCE :-) But don't quite understand what you want to achieve differently from how it is behaving?

Comment: i want to restrict the target area, so the user would drag Strings just between the JLists, currently, when im under kde desktop, i can drag Strings to the desktop or even to the eclipse editor and i dont want this.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe helpful for somebody else:
You need to create your own DatFlavor, that will only be accepted by your own application.

```
DataFlavor myObjectDataFlavor = new DataFlavor(MyObject.class, "java/MyObject");
```

Pass this one instead of a default `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor` or `DataFlavor.stringFlavor`. Your class `MyObject` is a Pojo containing only a class variable of type String or an integer or whatever you need.